# How to fill missing date by Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I am using python/pandas to process time series data in the following foramt:

```
index, date, name, value
1, 01/05/2017, x, 1.1
2, 05/06/2017, x, 2.3
3, , x, 5.4
```

On line 3, the date is missing. My question is if Pandas can fill the missing date by some algorithm (like interpolate, extrapolate, etc.)

Answer (score 0):

I can think of two methods that should be helpful in your case:

1- Using the [fillna() method](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.fillna.html) in pandas

2- Using the [Imputer class](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.Imputer.html) in scikit-learn